# Is there a way to redirect a user logging out of the Wagtail admin?

Tags: wagtail

I'm using django-allauth for user authentication to the Wagtail admin on my wagtail site. The user logs in at /accounts/login instead of the usual Wagtail /admin/login and is then redirected to /admin. Works great. However upon logging out they are left at /admin/login. It's confusing for the user as now there are two locations for logging in.

I'd like if possible to be able to redirect the users away from the Wagtail admin at /admin/login. There really is no need for it to be accessed at all since it's been replaced.

Django uses the

**LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL**

configuration which works with django-allauth but not Wagtail. Wagtail has

**WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_URL**

but nothing I could find for logging out.

Comment: This is afaik the Django class based LogoutView. So override the route and point to your own custom logout view to implement your custom behaviour. Off course this custom view might be a subclass of Django.auth.views.LogoutView

Comment: Thanks @allcaps for the suggestion, it gives me a good starting point. I've been detoured to some higher priority issues but I'll be back to finish this once time permits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being much more simple than I thought. I have a 'users' app that handles authentication etc. In that app views.py I added a simple Django logout request and returned a redirect:

```
# users/views.py

from django.contrib import auth
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/accounts/login')
```

Then in my main apps urls.py I imported my new users.view and overrode the wagtail logout:

```
# project_app/urls.py

from users import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='wagtailadmin_logout'),
    ...
]
```

Now the users never see the default Wagtail login page upon logging out.